# Acute triangle from a stick

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

A rod is randomly cut at two points. What is the probability that the three resulting parts form an acute angled triangle. I tried to use the inequality that sum of square of two sides should be greater than the square of third but it gets cumbersome quickly.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. There are 3 scenarios: 1)
Are we cutting the rod at 2 random points at the same time and try to make a triangle? 2) Are we cutting the rod at some point, and then the largest part is cut again? 3) Are we cutting the rod at some point and then we pick any of the two sticks by chance to cut again? These yield three different probabilities for being able to make a triangle. I suspect you imply the first scenario...

Comment: Its the first scenario. We are cutting at 2 random points at the same time.

Comment: If the condition that the triangle is acute, is dropped, than the probability is $1/4$, that is, the probability that a triangle can be formed with the sticks according to the first scenario, is $1/4$. ( I can elaborate if you wish) But if the triangle also has to be acute, then I wouldn't know how to do that. Maybe someone else knows...